# Wireless Display Adaptor not detected by MacBook Air

Tags: display, wifi, airplay

I am trying to display my MacBook Air screen on a TV screen, using a Wireless Display Adaptor. The TV is not an Apple TV. Although the Display dialogue under System Preferences show the option to "Show mirroring options" there are no devices detected alongside "AirPlay Display".

I have tried the function "Detect Displays", but this makes no difference - the Mac is not able to detect devices.

Could this be because the Wireless Display Adaptor is a Microsoft device?  The device documentation suggests Macs should be able to mirror ok.

Answer (score 3):

As per [Microsoft Wireless Display Adapter's Store Page](https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-us/products/adapters/microsoft-wireless-display-adapter/cg4-00001#specsColumns-testCarousel):

> **Operating systems**
>
> *Mac OS X*
>
> Mac OS 10.10  (Not Compatible)
> Mac OS 10.9  (Not Compatible)
> Mac OS 10.8  (Not Compatible)
> Mac OS 10.7  (Not Compatible)

[In all likelihood, 10.11/10.12/10.13 and later are not compatible as well]

**It will not work with a Mac.**